# Load data into object after Unlocked package

Tags: package, unlocked-package, unmanaged-package, 2gp, 2gp-ama

I want to load some data into an object after a package gets installed. I tried using a post-install script but seems these only work for Second-Generation Managed packages and *not* for Unlocked Packages.

Is there a way I can load data into an object once my unlocked package is successfully installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no automated way to load the data. You could use something like `sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert` or `sfdx force:apex:execute` to automate importing data, but this needs to be a separate step. Unlocked Packages are not meant to be used in a subscriber/ISV model, so there's no provision for a post-install script.